# Error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: in php PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

im a newbie in php and im facing this problem...i get with it 3 days and im going mad... ;). Im trying to implement a table with users of a web application. So i have to check that the user doesnt exist.

My sql table:

```
DROP TABLE users;
CREATE TABLE users (
    idUser INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    mail VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    role enum ("admin", "user"), 
    state BOOLEAN,
    forgotpass VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

Also this code works ( test if the user already exists in the table):

```
//$query="SELECT mail FROM proba.users WHERE mail='{$correu}'";
   $sql = 'SELECT  * FROM users WHERE mail = :mailparam';
    //$sql = 'SELECT  * FROM users';
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

  // 2. execute to insert a row 
  // with an associative array
  $stmt->execute(
      array(':mailparam'=>$correuFormulari)
      );

  // 3. get all rows
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach ($rows as $rowActual) {
    echo $rowActual['mail'] . "<br>";
   echo $rowActual['password'] . "<br>";
 }
```

But following the same logic i cant insert an element:

```
 if(count($rows) > 0){

        echo "L'usuari ja existeix";
        echo "<p><a href='registreUsuari.php'>Torna</a></p>";

    } else{
        echo "Usuari no trobat. Passem a insertar";
        //INSERT INTO users (mail, password, role, name, created_at,forgotpass) VALUES ("p@gmail.com", "pepe","user", "pepito", current_Time,"forgotpass");
        $user="admin";
        $sqlinsert = 'INSERT INTO users (mail, password, role, name,forgotpass) VALUES (:mail, :passwordform,:usuari, :nomFormulari,:forgotpass)';
    //$sql = 'SELECT  * FROM users';
        $stmtinsertar = $con->prepare($sqlinsert);
       // $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (mail, password, role, name, created_at,forgotpass) VALUES (:mail, :password,:user, :nomFormulari, :data,:forgotpass)");
      /*  $stmtinsertar->bindParam(':mail', $correuFormulari);
        $stmtinsertar->bindParam(':password', $passwordFormulari);
        $stmtinsertar->bindParam(':user', $user);
        $stmtinsertar->bindParam(':nomFormulari', $nomFormulari);
        //$stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
        $stmtinsertar->bindParam(':forgotpass', "forgotpass");

        INSERT INTO users (mail, password, role, name,forgotpass) VALUES ("hola@g,aoñ", "pepe","user", "pedro","forgot")
        */
        try
            { 
                //$stmtinsertar->execute();
                $stmt->execute(
                    array(':mail'=> "$correuFormulari",
                    ':passwordform'=>  "$passwordFormulari",
                    ':usuari'=>  "$user",
                    ':nomFormulari'=> "$nomFormulari",
                    ':forgotpass'=> "forgotpass")
                    );
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            handle_sql_errors($selectQuery, $e->getMessage());
        }
        

        echo "S'ha creat l'usuari";
        //header('Location: '.'login.php');

//        $stmt->close();
       

    }
```

I enter in the correct if, but i cant insert into the table....
The error shows something like:

```
pepekjjp@gamil.comConexio : object(PDO)#2 (0) { } hoola0Usuari no trobat. Passem a insertar

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

As you can read in the code i also tried to use bind->Params....

Any help would be apreciated.

Also would like to know, which form of executing PDO is preferred, using bindParameter or using an array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a typo. Parameter name is `usuari` and you bind `$stmtinsertar->bindParam(':user', $user);` Also you should cleanup your code before you share it

Comment: The same happens with password and passwordform

Comment: So which is a best practice...using an array with all parameters, or bind line by line one parameters from the form or the code to the users table field...like $stmtinsertar->bindParam(':password', $passwordFormulari);..Thanks